# Categories with zero morphisms

Tags: category-theory

I am looking to find a bunch of examples for the categories with zero morphisms which they are not additive categories. I guess one of them is the category of pointed topological spaces but I do not know the proof and then my intuition is that this category will help us to find other examples by considering slice categories of some special categories.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simply possible to forget the additive structure of additive categories with zero morphisms?

Comment: Definitely it is possible but I am looking for non trivial examples like this.

Comment: Take any category which is not additive and simply add a zero element (and it's unique morphisms)?

Comment: @NeitherNor You are right but it is not also what I am looking for.

Comment: Take any category $\mathcal{C}$ with a terminal object $1$ and take the undercategory ${}^{1 /} \mathcal{C}$, for example. Or the category of groups. etc.

Comment: @NeitherNor In some sense you can't really forget the additive structure, it's a property of the category.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thanks a lot. I have accepted your idea as a solution. May you write it? If you decide to write it please also point out that why this idea also works for the category of the pointed topological spaces. If you want I will write it as a solution.